# Is it possible to install the Nexus One Calendar app on the Samsung Galaxy S Captivate?

Tags: applications, calendar

I've been using the Galaxy S for a little while now, first on the stock 2.1, and then on stock 2.2. I'm mostly happy with this phone, but one of the things that I don't like is the Calendar app that comes with it (most of all - the fact that the it doesn't display the appointment titles on weekly displays).

So I've been looking for various calendars in the market, but the version that I remember being most happy with is the Calendar that comes installed in the Nexus One.

Is there some way to install it on another phone?

Comment: Did you manage this ? I too am looking for a better calendar application than the default one on my Galaxy S.

Comment: @Edelcom I'm guessing he did not, after a long search I could only find a N1-style calendar for the SGS on 2.1, not 2.2.  I might try to port one myself.

Comment: No, sadly, I did not manage this.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to find someone who's extracted it to an APK file, and side-load it onto your Galaxy. [This link](http://imvivo.com/tabid/104/IndexId/1952854/Default.aspx) gives a nice tutorial on how to side-load an app.

Probably the best place to start to find it extracted would be in the forums [on XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/).

Comment: Do you have a link to an APK file we can use? I don't believe you have to side-load the app if it's an APK. I've installed plenty of apps extracted from the Nexus One (e.g. Car Home, Gmail 2.2.1) onto a HTC Desire without having to side-load them.

Comment: I don't... extracting apps is not in my skillset.  :)  . Some of us do have to side-load even APKs though, thanks to AT&T who locked our phones out of installing anything that isn't through the market. I get why they did it, but they should've at least given us an option to re-enable it if were are more advanced users. Grrr.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Jorte. It offers several different views (daily, weekly, monthly, agenda, tasks, etc., and several different widgets for the different views. The widgets come in several different sizes too.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9877358&postcount=3), while for the facinate, has the calendar files needed. You will have to delete (backup them first) the TouchWizCalendar.apk & "original" CalendarProvider.apk. Then put the "stock" Calendar.apk and CalendarProvider.apk on the device.

You will have to have root to do this since these files are in /system/app.

Comment: I have done exactly this - but the calendar fails to work correctly. I've tried using the pre-existing CalendarProvider.apk with the current calendar, but the sync now only works one way (it takes events from my google calendar, but does not post them back), and trying to access the "Calendar" menu option results in the app crashing...